# How can I solve this dependency issue between Fantom pods afBedNap, afBounce and afBedSheet?

Tags: fantom, afbedsheet

I found an issue trying to install [afBedNap](http://www.fantomfactory.org/pods/afBedNap). The process went...

```
fanr install -r http://repo.status302.com/fanr/ afBedNap

afBedNap    [upgrade  ]  0.0.18 => 0.0.20
afBedSheet  [downgrade]  1.4.2  => 1.3.16
...
Installation successful (2 pods)
```

Then I tried to create myBedNap

```
fan afBedNap -copyto /Users/lightdye/Documents/myBedNap -podname myBedApp
```

But got:

```
sys::UnknownTypeErr: afIoc::ServiceStat
    at fan.sys.UnknownTypeErr.make(UnknownTypeErr.java:25)
    at fan.sys.UnknownTypeErr.make(UnknownTypeErr.java:22)
    at fan.sys.Pod.type(Pod.java:284)
...
java.lang.Exception: Missing dependency for 'afBedNap': afEfanXtra 1.1
```

Then I ran

```
fanr install -r http://repo.status302.com/fanr/ afEfanXtra

afEfan      [upgrade]  1.4.0.1 => 1.4.2
afEfanXtra  [upgrade]  1.1.12  => 1.1.20
...
Installation successful (2 pods)
```

And tried again to create myBedNap but this time I got:

```
java.lang.Exception: Missing dependency for 'afBounce': afBedSheet 1.3.16 != afBedSheet 1.4.0-1.4
...
java.lang.Exception: Missing dependency for 'afBedNap': afBounce 1.0
```

So I ran:

```
fanr install -r http://repo.status302.com/fanr/ afBounce

afBedSheet  [upgrade]  1.3.16 => 1.4.0
afBounce    [skip   ]  1.0.18 => 1.0.18
...
Installation successful (2 pods)
```

Please note that here it changed the afBedSheet version back up to 1.4.0, which was downgraded when I installed afBedNap in the first place. When I tried again to create myBedNap again, this time I got:

```
fan afBedNap -copyto /Users/lightdye/Documents/myBedNap -podname myBedApp
java.lang.Exception: Missing dependency for 'afBedNap': afBedSheet 1.4.0 != afBedSheet 1.3
```

At this point there is a loop that I don’t know how to break (or even if I can brake it): afBedNap requires afBedSheet 1.3.16 and afBounce but afBounce requires afBedSheet 1.4.0 which afBedNap can't use. How can I solve this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch! Yes, the dependencies certainly got out of sync somehow.

Your post prompted the release of BedNap 0.0.22 which depends on all the new / current versions of the pods.

Try re-installing the latest BedNap and try again:

```
fanr install -r http://repo.status302.com/fanr/ afBedNap
```